# How much classical information is transmitted in continuous variable teleportation?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer, quantum-teleportation

In order to do quantum teleportation of $n$ qubits, you need to send $2n$ bits of classical information, in order to ensure that you get the original state and not a relative phase change of the original state.

My question is, how much classical information do you need to send in order to do quantum teleportation of a continuous variable like position?  There are uncountably many relative phase changes of a quantum state in the position basis, so do you need to send an uncountable amount of information?

That would of course be physically impossible, but is there a way to do it with only a finite amount of classical information?

Comment: Very interesting question! I would like to throw out the idea/speculation that, given you have an analogue quantum system,  you may need to allow analogue classical communication. (eg perhaps the answer is you need 2 real numbers, where each real number corresponds in some sense to infinite bits). If I have any thoughts on how you might actually go about showing this I will return to post an answer.

Comment: @Dast So would that mean that it’s physically impossible to do continuous variable quantum teleportation, since it would be physically impossible to transmit, receive, process, and react to an uncountably infinite amount of classical information in a finite amount of time?

Comment: did you have a look at topical reviews, eg ([Pirandola, Mancini 2006](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0604027))?

Comment: @glS I have skimmed some continuous variable quantum teleportation papers, but I wasn’t readily able to find the answer.

Comment: In effect, as per the topical review by Pirandola/Mancini, Alice needs to communicate two real numbers. The number of bits required depends on the precision of continuous variable: no one can send $x=\pi$, but one can send $x\approx 3.14$, and three digits can be encoded in finite number of bits according to the conversion rules (e.g., using binary expansion of 3.14).

Comment: @Everiana So given that the measurements that yield the real numbers you have to transmit have only finite precision, how does transmitting an approximation of the real numbers rather than the exact real numbers impact the fidelity of the teleportion?  Will the received state be “close” in some well-defined sense to the sent state?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I am not familiar with the CV side myself, but even for finite-dimensions usually fidelity won't be perfect for various reasons, and I am fairly sure various distance measures are used to bound the errors. This is where looking into a review's references may help.

Comment: @Everiana : I am so happy to hear that it is two real numbers! Guessing the most elegant possible answer in this case turned up good.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan : Lets say we have infinite precision and all our measurements are completely perfect, in both are quantum system and our classical communication. In this case we really can send two real numbers to infinite precision, say we send two particles whose position coordinates are the numbers. In practice the sender's ability to prepare the two classical continuous variables is limited by finite precision (and so is the receiver's measurement), but this is also true for the CV quantum computer! A classical piece of analogue data has some finite precision, same for a quantum one.